# AWS CLI Invalid JSON Error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I'm writing an AWS reliant application in javascript and I'm utilizing the AWS CLI to automate the build process for my AWS resources. I'm attempting to create an API Gateway resource with CORS enabled. While calling the `put-integration-response` method of the api gateway CLI, when I add the `--response-parameters` argument, I received the following error:

```
>> Error parsing parameter '--response-parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
>> JSON received: {method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'}
```

Here is the --response-parameters argument that is causing issues:

`--response-parameters {"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"\'*\'"}`

If it helps, this argument is being fed via the grunt-exec plugin for Grunt. What exactly is causing this issue? I've tried adding more double quotes, but they don't seem to appear in 'JSON received'.

Comment: It seems you missed to wrap the parameters in single quote. --response-parameters '{"method.response.header.custom-header": "'"'"'custom-value'"'"'"}'   This link has nice example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/put-integration-response.html

Comment: So I need to wrap the entire JSON string in single quotes? I'll try that now.

Comment: I would give a try with that. Make sure quotes are properly closed and escaped.

Comment: Updated input: `--response-parameters \'{"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"\'*\'"}\'`

Result:
    `>> Error parsing parameter '--response-parameters': Expected: '=', 
    received: '''
    for input:
    >> '{method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'}'`

Unfortunately, this creates a new error.

Comment: This seems different issue than original, now parser could understand KEY, but failing to locate value.

Comment: Why did you put \'?

Comment: The commands are being processed by Grunt, a javascript framework, and the strings are inline. The values of the strings are surrounded by single quotes, so I need to escape any single quotes within the string itself.

Comment: Got it, my guess is, these encoding characters causing issue. Did you validate that without encoding characters, JSON error didn't happen?

Comment: I would suggest this online JSON parser: http://json.parser.online.fr/, when I tried {"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"\\'*‌​\\'"}, I got success with value as {
"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"\'*‌​\'"
} you might need to play with this tool get successful JSON you want.

Comment: The command doesn't work via simple command entry either. I've tried adding quotes, removing quotes, etc. It doesn't seem to be a problem with grunt but a problem with the command itself.

Comment: I might know answer for this issue, which box your AWS CLI is installed on? Windows, Linux, Mac etc.,?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: Could you try the solution described here, the one 'windows cmd you can change single quotes (') to double quotes etc.,, https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-dynamodb/discussion/-KUX8EQjmN7F2pNKvoWW/?answer=-KXh-a7NIDibsq4dbAsR

Comment: Once I'm back in the office I'll see if this does it. Thank you

Answer (score 20):

Here is another fix for this problem from [here](https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-dynamodb/discussion/-KzG6wJR9LDKNioVICJ9/single-quotes-in-aws-cli-options?answer=-Kze0LRHpihdQ5dDZHH-)

Basically you use \ before quotes inside of JSON on Windows:
Linux/Mac:

```
 --expression-attribute-values '{ ":u": {"S":"anotherUser"}}'
```

will be like this on Windows:

```
--expression-attribute-values '{ \":u\": {\"S\":\"anotherUser\"}}'
```

Hope it helps to fix your error

Comment: Thank you ! This should be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while following an [AWS Lambda Functions tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-configure-event-source.html)
where I couldn't get the *response-models* argument to accept JSON (on Windows 10) no matter what I tried. I finally figured it out: I created a file named *response-models.json* with the contents on the first line of the file as **{"application/json": "Empty"}** and I saved it in the current directory.  Then as the value of the *response-models* argument I used  **file://response-models.json**
*IMPORTANT:* the file must be saved in a format WITHOUT the BOM so that only the ASCII characters will come out of it and no other gibberish. (I used Sublime Text which allows one to save in UTF-8 with no BOM, as well as many other formats.)
Et Voila!  I got back the following response:

```
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "responseModels": {
        "application/json": "Empty"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too. Frustrating as the AWS documentation claims you can enclose in single quotes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html#cli-using-param-json. However clearly this doesn't work as you get this response "Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Comment: Hi what if I want to parse json values to Terraform, I got similar error, I posted this in this question, would be very appreciated if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938396/json-parsing-error-when-running-aws-stepfunctions-update-state-machine-via-ter

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the static value by "'"'"'*'"'"'".

Example:

```
aws apigateway put-integration-response --rest-api-id xxxxx --resource-id xxxxxx --http-method GET --status-code 200 --response-parameters '{"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'"'"'*'"'"'"}'
```

I suggest to use the JavaScript SDK to call API Gateway to manage your resources. You can find more information from the [SDK documentation.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html)

Comment: Hi what if I want to parse json values to Terraform, I got similar error, I posted this in this question, would be very appreciated if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938396/json-parsing-error-when-running-aws-stepfunctions-update-state-machine-via-ter